# Failed to install angular cli using command line

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I was trying to install angular cli using the command.

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

But it throws the following error:

```
npm ERR! path /usr/bin/ng<br>
npm ERR! code EEXIST<br>
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/bin/ng: ../lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli<br>
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/bin/ng<br>
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.<br>
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR! /home/sachin/.npm/_logs/2018-11-06T13_58_33_153Z-debug.log
```

I have tried the following command

```
sudo npm cache clear --force
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ng
```

But got the same above error every time.

Comment: check whether ng exists

Comment: @Seenivasan How to do that?

Comment: @sachinmukherjee `ng --version`

Comment: and `sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/ng` ?

Comment: It shows the following output `The program 'ng' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:sudo apt install ng-common`.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

- `sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
- `sudo npm cache clean`
- `sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/ng` *=> Option to ensure*
- `sudo npm i -g @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: While running the command `sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` got the same error as mentioned above in the question.

Comment: @sachinmukherjee try the installation without `sudo` .